# How can I see all messages between me and moderators?

Tags: support, users, moderators, moderator-messages

How can I see all messages between me and moderators?

Where are they stored?

I know that they have links like:

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/message/**`[natural number]`**

But, how can I get them?

Comment: If you have so many, or for so long, that you need to keep track, you probably have bigger problems.

Comment: @michaelb958 No, I just want to read again a message that I've received from a moderator about 1 year ago.

Comment: @Johnツ Fair point there.

Comment: @Bart And which is the answer?...

Comment: @Johnツ from the duplicate I assume it's "if you don't find it in your notifications, and you don't have the email any more, you're out of luck".

Comment: @Bart Is't there another solution?

Comment: Never been on the receiving end of a moderator message. So I have no clue and no way to verify.

Comment: @Bart Hmmm... I think I will found a solution using a script.

Comment: Using a script how? You're going to poll all possible numbers and see if something comes back?

Comment: Please post your script on the other question, no need in two same questions.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ok. You are right.