# How can a user view an (old) moderator message?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, moderator-messages

While doing some research for an answer to another post, I wanted to get a screenshot of a moderator message I'd sent to an alternate account. While "moderator view" lets me view the history of the moderator messages to someone (so if it wasn't my alt, "Aibobot" would have to ask a friendly moderator nicely for a link).

From a moderator perspective - If I need to reference an 'old' mod message, for example for a recalcitrant user who claims not to remember a previous moderator message, I *could* link back to the moderator message specifically, but it seems weird to have the content of those messages visible but impossible to find.

Is there some way I'm missing for a regular, non-moderator user to view mod messages sent to them on the site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we see the private messages that moderators sent us?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94779/how-do-we-see-the-private-messages-that-moderators-sent-us) (Or [How can I see all messages between me and moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194943/how-can-i-see-all-messages-between-me-and-moderators), which is closed as a duplicate of the former)

Answer (score 8):

The only way I've found is to scroll back through the inbox until you find it.

Once you've read it there's not really any easy way for a non-mod to find a mod message sent to them.

Comment: Yeah, or email. Just seems very "filing cabinet in a disused toilet"

Comment: I [wrote a script](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/59b3fd67d37e81994547506f7eed18d9) to [investigate inbox message types](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319354/295232); I guess it could be turned into something that lists moderator messages in your inbox instead.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Which, given the nature of what mod messages are supposed to be used for, makes sense. If the mod messaged user rehabilitates and participates constructively, it makes little sense to have a place where past transgressions are very visible. If they don't, then it makes sense those still are very visible to moderators though :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just go in your email through which you have registered your StackExchange Id. Then on search box type `do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email`. For better finding write `do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email moderator` and get the result

[image]

Edit: Since OP want how to see the message on site here is one way-

Go to your network profile and click on Inbox or go [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/19432115/current?tab=inbox&page=1)

Then click on `Ctrl` and `F` and type moderator message. If you didn't get the word in page 1 go to page 2 and not in page 2 then go to next page and so on. This will make it a bit easy to find moderator message.

Comment: I specifically meant through the site - some users (ill advisedly) use disposable email addresses, or might delete emails. Being on the site also means there's a certain consistency in what we see...